# Joomla - Overriding getItem method

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, overriding, joomla2.5

I want to override the method getItem() found in file \administrator\components\com_content\models\article.php

*line 257* `public function getItem($pk = null)`

I need to modify the return value based on the value of variable $pk.

How do I do this?

I am hoping to find a way to not to modify the core.

Also, if override is possible, can I make a plugin out of it?

Am using Joomla 2.5.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some more searching, came across a beautiful solution.

All I needed was to override the model (article.php) under com_content. This got it done.

Using the [Plugin Override](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/15611) plugin the Joomla core can be overridden. Found a great article on the same on [digitaldisseny](http://www.digitaldisseny.com/en/blog/94-joomla-override-model-view-controller-part-one)

The documentation on overriding Joomla! core's MVC using this is [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Hope it helps others too.

Any better ideas are highly welcome.