# Joomla - Where is the code in K2 which saves a new item's Title and alias

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I have looked every where in the administrator\components\com_k2 folder but am not able to find the code that saves a new item\article in K2. I checked the item.php file under models folder. No luck.

I need to override the K2 item save method.

I need a know the exact method that saves the Item's title and alias into the #__K2_content table.

I have to duplicate the K2 items in joomla articles on save and remove on trash/delete.

I have successfully been able to override the K2 core code. But am unable to find the right code to override. (override method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966202/joomla-overriding-getitem-method))

Comment: I went through the code, it looks like K2 uses Joomla's methods: see _administrator/components/com_k2/controllers/item.php_ - line 24: `function save()`. Everything is extended from Joomla classes.

Comment: Oh thanks, will checkit out once I return from work. I primarily focussed on the item.php under models folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table that stores the K2 items (at least in the latest K2 version - 2.6.5) is `#__k2_items`, not #__k2_content.

I went through the code, it looks like K2 uses Joomla's methods: see administrator/components/com_k2/controllers/item.php - line 24: function save(). Everything is extended from Joomla classes.

```
class K2ControllerItem extends K2Controller
{

    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())
    {
        JRequest::setVar('view', 'item');
        parent::display();
    }

    function save()
    {
        JRequest::checkToken() or jexit('Invalid Token');
        $model = $this->getModel('item');
        $model->save();
    }
    .....
}
```

The K2 controller: /administrator/components/com_k2/controllers/controller.php

```
...
else if (version_compare(JVERSION, '2.5', 'ge'))
{
    class K2Controller extends JController
    {
        public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
        {
            parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);
        }

    }

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shaz, you gave me the right direction to look into.

in com_k2\controllers\item.php
this `$model->save();`saves the data.

The function save() is in the com_k2\models\item.php file, where there are two lines that capture the data.

```
$row = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
```

this initiates the $row, while

```
if (!$row->bind(JRequest::get('post')))
```

this populates $row.

So now $row contains all the variable values.

Now, this `if (!$row->store())` saves the data.

I will use $row to save the same for the Joomla! articles in com_content.

Feels Good :)